# Is Outside In's PDF Export library's function EXOpenExport thread-safe?

Tags: thread-safety, oracle-outside-in

I'm writing a C++ wrapper, for Node.js, around the `Oracle Outside In PDF Export` library, on Ubuntu Linux. Node.js has a single threaded event loop and therefor any long-running processing is done on a worker thread. So, my wrapper is calling all of the PDF Export methods inside of this worker thread. I mention this so that you can be sure of two things: this is a threaded environment, and all PDF Export functions are being called on the same worker thread. Also, I am not making use of any redirected IO or PDF Export-handled threading. I've initialized the library specifying to use no threads. So all of this processing should be occurring within the thread that I call the functions on.

Everything seems to go fine when exporting a single PDF or even maybe two or three in quick succession. When I up the number of PDFs that I try to export to 5+, I receive a SIGSEGV segmentation fault from within the OIT libs. The back trace is below:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff4fd0700 (LWP 1577)]
0x00007fffeef1da26 in HandlePoolCreateHandle () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffeef1da26 in HandlePoolCreateHandle () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
#1  0x00007fffeef1925d in Win32VCreateHandle () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
#2  0x00007fffed49046b in WrapBrush(void*, GdiBrush*) () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libos_pdf.so
#3  0x00007fffed46e8c8 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libos_pdf.so
#4  0x00007fffed46df63 in GNGetOutputSolutionInfoAt () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libos_pdf.so
#5  0x00007fffeef1e32a in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
#6  0x00007fffeef1e214 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
#7  0x00007fffeef18ed3 in Win32VLoadOS () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libwv_core.so
#8  0x00007fffeddffb24 in VwExportOpen () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libex_pagelayout.so
#9  0x00007ffff4062c4d in FAOpenExport () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libsc_fa.so
#10 0x00007ffff7e53270 in EXOpenExport () from /usr/local/lib/pdfexport/libsc_ex.so
#11 0x00007ffff43c0a4d in topdf_convert(uv_work_s*) ()
   from /home/ryan/repos/pdf-service/node_modules/topdf/build/Release/topdf.node
#12 0x00000000006e2ec7 in worker (arg=<optimized out>) at ../deps/uv/src/unix/threadpool.c:65
#13 0x00007ffff6fa6e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#14 0x00007ffff6cd3cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#15 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I'll explain the back trace a little. The function on #11 is the function inside my code. That is the function in which I call all of the OIT lib functions. The functions on lines #12 and higher are the Node.js-related threading functions, setting up the thread to run my code's function. Functions on lines #10 down to #1 are all the OIT-called functions.

In the documentation for PDF Export, it says that if you're going to be using this library inside a threaded environment, then you need to call the init and deinit functions each time within the worker thread. I'm doing this in my code, which you can see here: https://github.com/ryancole/topdf/blob/master/src/topdf.cc#L29-L74

Is there anything else that I need to be setting that would cause this? I'm only specifying the font directory, explicitly. Are these libraries actually thread-safe? It doesn't look like they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle Outside In V 8.4.0 documentation (Chapter 4.2, page 50)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26550_01/dev.840/e12887.pdf) your call to `DAInitEx` is wrong, check the first param...

> DAInitEx should only be called once per application, at application
>   startup time. Any number of documents can be opened for access between
>   calls to DAInitEx and DADeInit. If DAInitEx succeeds, DADeInit must be
>   called regardless of any other API calls.

and

> Multiple threads are supported for all Windows platforms and the
>   32-bit versions of Linux x86 and Solaris SPARC. Failed initialization
>   of the threading function will not impair other API calls. If
>   threading isn't initialized or fails, stub functions are called
>   instead of mutex functions.

Comment: Hmm, I took that to mean that if I call `DAInitEx` with something other than `DATHREAD_INIT_NOTHREADS`, then the library will spawn its own threads calling my callback functions. This line is why I'm confused there, I guess: `The developer must actually code the threads after this function has been called.` Also, lower in those docs it says this about running threads: `On certain platforms, export products may be run in a multithreaded or 
multiprocessing application. The thing to remember when doing so is that each thread 
must go through all the steps listed in Chapter 1, "Introduction."`

Comment: @Ryan since I don't have this library here I can't play around with it :-(

Comment: Yahia, well you seem to have been correct anyway! I changed it to the PTHREAD option and that seems to work. I just misunderstood the documentation I guess, and never thought to try that option. Thank you. :)